# Arcgis select by attribute the day of the week in date field

Tags: arcgis-desktop, select-by-attribute, datetime

I am trying to select a specific day in the "Select by attributes" tool.
I know you can select using  a day from 0-31 like this:

```
EXTRACT(DAY FROM "TimeStampStart") = 5
```

**But I was wondering is there a way to select a specific day in the week (sunday to saturday)? for example select only days of week =  tuesday?**

P.S
This is not the answer I am looking for:
https://pdgisusers.org/2010/12/15/extract-day-of-the-week-from-a-date-field-in-arcgis/

and already looked into this :http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000011531

I have a csv file with a datetime field.
[image: g]

Comment: Could you post a sample CSV file?

Comment: added to the main

Comment: Could you post a sample CSV file *as text*?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use some Python, it's pretty simple to extract the day of week.
There's some limitations working with `csv`, but the following should be a good starting point:

```py
table = "test.csv"

# list of days to extract, starting with Monday at 1
days = [1,2,3,4,5]

# First field is unique key field used for select, second is date field
# Would be "OID@" if a GDB table
fields = ['Field1', 'Field2']

# Find all key field values
keys = [k for k,d in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table, fields)
            if d.isoweekday() in days]

# Make new view with selection, export, etc.
sql = "{} IN ({})".format(fields[0], ",".join(map(str, keys)))
arcpy.MakeTableView_management(table, "selection", sql)
```

It would be trivial to create a toolbox script that takes a `csv` and day(s) of week as input (maybe even the field names as well).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but this isn't what I am looking for, is there a way to use sql inside arcgis in select table to get the day of the week?

Comment: @Golan, I don't believe it is possible if you are using `csv`. Might not be possible in a GDB table either.

Comment: even though its a date type field? if I use the convert time field tool I can create a new field with the days and select it. but thats not what I am after. anyways thanks

Comment: @Golan, if you look at your initial link, not every database supports the different queries. `csv` is still just a flat file, so your querying capabilities will be quite limited. What are you looking to use this `csv` for? Would be simpler to pre-process in python for example and then bring into ArcMap.

Comment: I have 15 files, each one of them has 4-5 million rows. Each file has samples for unique dates. I am buidling a tool in model builder and I am trying  the fastest way to select only Saturday and wednesday from those files. Since selecting those days isn't possible as a simple query I now need to check all the dates for all the days I need to query (Dates for saturdays and wednesdays) in the meantime Ive manage to use this query: EXTRACT(DAY FROM "Field4") = 13. 13 is just an example for lets say 13.7 (wednesday)

Comment: @Golan, with such large `csv` files, I'd suggest you look into importing that into a database; you'll get much better performance. sqlite is a good starting place